# How to get the foreground activity instance?

Tags: android, android-activity, foreground

I want to create an service app which sends screen-touch events timely to foregound activity. The foregound activity is probably a 3pp application.

My codes:

```
public void myClickEvent(float x, float y) {
    long firstTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    final MotionEvent firstEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(firstTime, firstTime,
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, x, y, 0);

    long secondTime = firstTime + 100;
    final MotionEvent secondEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(secondTime,
            secondTime, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, x, y, 0);

    dispatchTouchEvent(firstEvent);
    dispatchTouchEvent(secondEvent);
}
```

But Service has no `dispatchTouchEvent()` as Activity has. 
The only way is to get the foreground activity instance in my service.
How to do it?
Thanks a lot for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can: 
1. Catch the event in your activity A.
2. Send data to activity B. You can use BroadcastReceiver.

If you need to send broadcasts across applications:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: In fact, activity A that runs foreground is not created by myself. It could be any app that I cannot modify, for example setting, games, etc.

The only thing I know is that activity A can handle screen-touch event, but how could I know what the current activity A is in my activity B?